# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference AngularJs Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, thymeleaf

Hey everyone am trying to make a validation  for a `form` with `AngularJS` in `Thymeleaf`

```
  <form name="registerForm" novalidate="">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Lastname *</label>
 <input id="lastname" type="text" ng-model="lastname" class="form-control" required="required" />
</div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
<label>Firstname *</label>
 <input id="firstname" type="text" ng-model="firstname"  class="form-control" required="required" />
</div>      
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
<label>Date of birth *</label>
 <input id="birth" type="date" ng-model="brith"  class="form-control" required="required" />
</div>   
</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">        
<div class="form-group">
    <label>email *</label>
 <input id="email" type="text" ng-model="email"  class="form-control" required="required" />
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Username *</label>
 <input id="user" type="text" ng-model="user"  class="form-control" required="required" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Acount Type *</label>
 <select ng-model="accout" class="form-control" required="required" >
 <option selected="">StartUp</option>
 <option>Entreprise</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.$dirty && registerForm.pass.$invalid, 'has-success': registerForm.pass.$valid}">
    <label>Password *</label>
 <input id="pass" name="pass" type="text" ng-model="pass" ng-minlength="6" class="form-control" required="required" />
 <span class="text-danger" ng-show="registerForm.pass.$error.minlength">Password Too Short</span>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">           
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.$dirty && registerForm.confpass.$invalid, 'has-success': registerForm.confpass.$valid}">
    <label>Confirm Password *</label>
 <input id="confpass" name="confpass"  type="text" ng-model="confpass"  class="form-control" equals-to="registerForm.pass" required="required" />
 <span ng-show="!registerForm.confpass.$error.required && registerForm.confpass.$error.equalsTo">Vérifiez votre mot de passe</span>
</div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" >Sign Up</button>
</div>


</div>
</div>
    </form>
```

This actually work in a simple `HTML` Page in `Thymeleaf`i get this kind of  error

```
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference
```

i've tried replacing the `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` 
the form validation wont work , am not having any errors but i don't think that the conditions are correct.

Comment: I'm guessing Thymeleaf doesn't like the `&&` in your `ng-class` directive. Have you tried making a controller function and replacing those condition tests with a single call to a function that returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: Well i got the idea but i wanted to search for solution to replace the `&` cause i may use it in somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf Doesn't Support &&.

You use  '**and**' instead of '**&&**'.

For Example :

```
<span ng-show="!registerForm.confpass.$error.required and registerForm.confpass.$error.equalsTo">Vérifiez votre mot de passe</span>
```